# Breakdown voltage of electronic devices

Tags: electrical-engineering, ac, semiconductor

Diode and transistor have reverse breakdown voltage. Are these devices permanently destroyed under such voltage? Also,  do these devices have breakdown voltage when AC voltage is applied? How much AC voltage and frequency these can tolerate,  say $1V$ at $50$ Hz,  $1V$ at $1$ MHz?