# What determines the breakdown voltage of diodes?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Some diodes have reverse breakdown voltage of 50v and some 1000v. What determines this difference?

Comment: Is this you? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/23278/10902

Comment: Reverse breakdown voltage is explained in detail in Principles of Semiconductor Devices. For me the the topic is fairly complex. May I ask your understanding of semiconductor device processing

Answer (score 1):

Avalanche multiplication and quantum mechanical tunneling of carriers through the bandgap are two methods that impact breakdown voltage. Generally breakdown voltage is dependent of the struct of the PN junction. Usually the breakdown voltage is dependent on the doping density. Check out some attached references.

**References:**

- [Reverse bias breakdown](https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter4/ch4_5.htm)